# Any tutorials, code help to implement Drag and drop functionality in WPF using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am using System.Windows.Interactivity to map mouse events in ViewModels.
Any tutorials, code help to implement Drag and drop functionality in WPF using MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

wpftutorial.net has a [drag&drop](http://wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html) tutorial.

You can also find a two-part tutorial on codeplex. ([Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43614/Drag-and-Drop-in-WPF), [Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43702/Drag-and-Drop-in-WPF-Part-II))

Answer (score 0):

here are good tutorials :

[Tutorial1](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2011/01/mvvm-drag-and-drop-part-1.html)
 
[Tutorial2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/420545/WPF-Drag-and-Drop-MVVM-using-Behavior)
[Tutorial3](http://www.wpfsharp.com/2012/03/22/mvvm-and-drag-and-drop-command-binding-with-an-attached-behavior/)
[Tutorial4](http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/jyoung/archive/2009/07/21/728.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

http://sharpfellows.com/post/WPF-Drag-and-Drop-e28093-doing-it-the-MVVM-way.aspx